# How can I develop a migration into phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble with migrating 'cover_image' to phpmyAdmin. Every time I attempt to upload a photo, an error shoots out:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cover_images' in 'field list'

Here is my code below:

```
if($request->hasFile('cover_image')) {
    //get``
    $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();

    //get filename
    $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    //get ext
    $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

    //upload image
    $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
} else {
    $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
}

//Create Post
$post = new Post;
$post->title = $request->input('title');
$post->body = $request->input('body');
$post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$post->cover_images = $fileNameToStore;
$post->save();

return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Post Created');
```

Comment: what part of error message is unclear?

Comment: what is the field name of image in database?

Comment: I want to migrate ‘cover_image’ to the database table so that I can upload pictures in the application. This line of code which appears 5 lines from the bottom:   $post->cover_images = $fileNameToStore;     causes this error. When I comment it out, error doesn’t occur and the picture does not display.

Comment: @SachinAghera there is no field name yet. I tried to migrate it, refresh the database, but still won’t work.

Comment: @SachinAghera field name suppose to be cover_image

Comment: You have to first add the field name in migration file with name cover_image and then you have to migrate it.

Comment: @SachinAghera I migrate it by typing in the terminal: php artisan migrate. Still nothing appears in the database column.

Comment: Are you sure about you add the column in migration file??

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function($table){
            $table->string('cover_image');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function($table){
            $table->dropColumn('cover_image');
        });
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Two possibilities of this error

- Maybe you forgot to add column for the image name in table structure.

> To add a new column to your table check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-tables):

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
php artisan create:migration add_cover_images_to_posts_table    --table=posts

Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table){
       $table->string('cover_images');
});
```

- You have column in table structure, but not same as you passing through your *save method*.
  Check your column name is `cover_images` in table structure.

Comment: I comment out $post->save();     and it works. Good news is that there is no more errors. Bad news is that the image is not displayed.

Comment: See if you will not use `$post->save()` record will not saved. By this your image is uploaded to local storage but not in the database.

Comment: If your image uploading to your database and storage both. then problem must have with the storage `symlink`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: How can I troubleshoot symlink then?

Comment: Check Now I updated my answer. maybe that will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I ran it but it still won’t create a column for ‘cover_images’ in table structure

Comment: Your problem with the column name. Okay, try the solution and check documentation also.

Comment: Awesome it works. I created a column name cover_image manually in the database. I uncommented the $post->save(); and the images appear